# Node js. Writing directory to the archive, without path to this directory

Tags: node.js, file

Got some task, it is not hard, but i have some trouble.
Maybe someone already has similar problem.

My task is writing to zip archive some folder, with files and other folders in it with using NodeJS

I try to use  AdmZip pakage

folder project structure:
[image]

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

let Archive = new AdmZip();
Archive.addLocalFolder('Archive/filesFolder', '');
Archive.writeZip('Archive/newArchive.zip);
```

I must get archive with 'filesFolder',  instead i get archive with 'Archive' folder and in it i have 'filesFolder'.

If anybody know, how to record only target folder, and not the sequence of a way  folders?

Comment: What happens if you change **Archive/filesFolder** to **/Archive/filesFolder**

Comment: it not wok.  i got error.

d:\Zip-Server\node_modules\adm-zip\adm-zip.js:261
                throw Utils.Errors.FILE_NOT_FOUND.replace("%s", localPath);
                ^
File not found: \Archive\files/

Comment: As indicated in my answer, change the value provided to **Archive.writeZip()** for testing purpose and see what happens. I don't know why you provided a second empty string arg to **Archive.addLocalFolder('Archive/filesFolder', ' ');** nothing about second arg in the documentation, and not sure why it says **let Archive** rather than **var Archive** - copy/paste the three line I have provided in my answer and see what is the output.

Comment: second arg it is the path inside the archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you are providing **Archive/filesFolder** as value to writeZip and that means include in the zip `Archive` folder and inside that include `filesFolder`.

For testing purpose change the value of `writeZip()` to just `filesFolder.zip` and it should zip content of `Archive` as `filesFolder.zip` in current working directory. See below (you can copy/paste the bit of code and run it and it should work).

```
var zip = new AdmZip();
// I don't know why you provided a second argument to below, I removed it
// There was nothing about it in the documentation. 
zip.addLocalFolder('./Archive');

//rename the value of the following to just filesFolder.zip
zip.writeZip('filesFolder.zip');
```

The above should output the content of `Archive` to the current working directory as `filesFolder.zip`

I did mention this in my comment and your commend seem to indicate that you have path issue, so try the above script.

Comment: I try this way

let Archive = new AdmZip();
    Archive.addLocalFolder('Archive/files');
    Archive.writeZip('newArchive.zip');

but it is not that i want. After that code i get archive with "Archive/files/..." inside.  But i want to get archive with "files/...." inside.

Comment: i change let to var, but get the same result

Comment: Where is your Archive/files directory? what happens if you change **Archive.addLocalFolder('Archive/files');** to **Archive.addLocalFolder('./Archive/files');** ? if possible attach a picture of the directory showing where your app.js or server.js is and where the Archive directory is.

Comment: if i do  

var Archive = new AdmZip();
    Archive.addLocalFolder('./Archive/files');
    Archive.writeZip('newArchive.zip');

i get the same result.  Folder Archive is inside my project folder

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your project directory? It would be easier to tell which path to provide to addLocalFolder and writeZip functions. You can edit your question to include the screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103216/discussion-between-raf-and-pj-infest).